# MVC DropDownListFor and collection not from model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have class student **created from existing database by Entity Framework** (I am not creating anything by hands) like following:

```
public class student
{
   ...
   public int student_status { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Also I have linked (by Navigation Property) collection of student statuses like:

```
public class student_status
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}
```

I using strongly-typed view (System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<EntityTypes.Models.Student>) and I want to display drop down list with studet statuses and selected - existing.

Note: student entity itsels does not contains collection of all statuses, i.e. data for list is not presented in model - I thought that I can pass it using ViewData.

I tried to use Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.student_status, ViewData["StudentStatuses"] as IEnumerable, htmlAttrs) but failed (ViewData["StudentStatuses"] is prepared in controller collection).

May be I can do ut using Navigation Property? I tried to understand .Include() instruction but have not luck.

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model's are fine the way they are.  I did change the spelling/syntax in my example.  So you will need to adjust if you copy and paste.

Here is the ActionMethods :

```
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult Index()
            {
                StudentModel model = new StudentModel();
                List<StudentStatus> StatusList = new List<StudentStatus>();
                StatusList.Add(new StudentStatus { Id = 1, Name = "In School" });
                StatusList.Add(new StudentStatus { Id = 2, Name = "Out of School" });
                ViewData["StatusList"] = StatusList;
                return View(model);
            }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(StudentModel model)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStatus, new SelectList(ViewData["StatusList"] as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "Id", "Name", @Model.SelectedStatus), "Select Status")
```

Model:

```
public class StudentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SelectedStatus { get; set; }
}



   public class StudentStatus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```